# How to Hide parameters in URL in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, url-rewriting

I don't want the user see the parameters in my URL.

**Example :**

```
my_route:
    path:     /***/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:myaction}
```

the route will be generated like this :

***/product/1

i want just see the

***/product

Comment: So when the server receives a direct request for `/product` how should it decide which product to show?

Comment: there is the Url rewriter how to do this so ?

Comment: You could rewrite `/product/1` to `/product/potato-pie`, but not to `/product`. Every url still needs some way to uniquely identify the resource.

Comment: you can give me how to do this plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments, the request needs something to identify the resource you want to fetch. But this has nothing to do with URL rewriting. If you want to display the slug of the resource instead of the id, do the following :

```
my_route:
    path:     /products/{slug}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:myaction}
```

Then, in MyBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php :

```
public function myactionAction(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->findOneBy(["slug" => $slug]);
}
```

and when you want to create a link to this product, use

```
<a href="{{ path('my_route', {'slug': product.slug}) }}">link to the product</a>
```